# How to refresh a single cell in ag-grid Fullrow edit

Tags: ag-grid

I want to refresh a row in ag-grid full row edit?

I want this to happen when the entire row is in editing mode

It works in non-editing mode and there is no problem, but in editing mode it doesn't show any reaction

```
this.gridOptionsByComponentId[ComponentId].redrawRows(rowNodes);
```